# How to drag and drop rows of a table

Tags: sapui5

In my view.xml file:

```
<html:div class="container-fluid">   
    <html:div class="row">
              <Table id="ConnectorModuleTable"
                       items="{
                            path: '/datalist'}">
                        <columns>
                            <Column ><Text text="Connector Module"/></Column>
                            <Column ><Text text="Setting A"/></Column>
                            <Column ><Text text="Setting B"/></Column>
                            <Column ><Text text="Custom Pin"/></Column>
                            <Column ><Text text="Actions"/></Column>
                        </columns>

                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                            <cells>
                                <Text text="{Connectormodule}" wrapping="false" />
                                <Text text="{settingA}" wrapping="false" />
                                <Text text="{settingB}" wrapping="false" />
                                <Text text="{settingB}" wrapping="false" />
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>
   </html:div>
    </html:div>
```

I am trying to drag and drop the rows of this table

I have referred the link from docs showing for list as:
[Documentation example link here](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.f.GridContainer/sample/sap.f.sample.GridContainerDragAndDropFromList)

The same I have applied with the table in controller as :

```
attachDragAndDrop: function () {
    var oList = this.byId("MyTable");

    oList.addDragDropConfig(new DragInfo({
        sourceAggregation: "items"
    }));
    oList.addDragDropConfig(new DropInfo({
        targetAggregation: "items",
        dropPosition: "Between",
        dropLayout: "Vertical",
        drop: this.onDrop.bind(this)
    }));

},

onDrop: function (oInfo) {

    var oDragged = oInfo.getParameter("draggedControl"),
        oDropped = oInfo.getParameter("droppedControl"),
        sInsertPosition = oInfo.getParameter("dropPosition"),

        oDraggedParent = oDragged.getParent(),
        oDroppedParent = oDropped.getParent(),

        oDragModel = oDraggedParent.getModel(),
        oDropModel = oDroppedParent.getModel(),
        oDragModelData = oDragModel.getData(),
        oDropModelData = oDropModel.getData(),

        iDragPosition = oDraggedParent.indexOfItem(oDragged),
        iDropPosition = oDroppedParent.indexOfItem(oDropped);

    // remove the item
    var oItem = oDragModelData[iDragPosition];
    oDragModelData.splice(iDragPosition, 1);

    if (oDragModel === oDropModel && iDragPosition < iDropPosition) {
        iDropPosition--;
    }

    // insert the control in target aggregation
    if (sInsertPosition === "Before") {
        oDropModelData.splice(iDropPosition, 0, oItem);
    } else {
        oDropModelData.splice(iDropPosition + 1, 0, oItem);
    }

    if (oDragModel !== oDropModel) {
        oDragModel.setData(oDragModelData);
        oDropModel.setData(oDropModelData);
    } else {
        oDropModel.setData(oDropModelData);
    }
},

initData: function (datalist) {
    this.byId("MyTable").setModel(new JSONModel([
        datalist

    ]));

}
```

Here `datalist` has all rows data in JSON (for ref)

But this did n't work , any help or guiding links are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following view with your onDrop() and it worked.
Can you describe, what is not working?

```
<Table id="MyTable" items="{/}">
    <columns>
        <Column ><Text text="Connector Module"/></Column>
        <Column ><Text text="Setting A"/></Column>
        <Column ><Text text="Setting B"/></Column>
    </columns>
    <dragDropConfig>
        <dnd:DragDropInfo
                sourceAggregation="items"
                targetAggregation="items"
                dropPosition="Between"
                drop=".onDrop"/>
    </dragDropConfig>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{Connectormodule}" wrapping="false" />
                <Text text="{settingA}" wrapping="false" />
                <Text text="{settingB}" wrapping="false" />
                <Text text="{settingB}" wrapping="false" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Comment: i am getting data as undefined  as:-                                                               

oDragModelData = (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined], oDragModel = constructor {pSequentialImportCompleted: Promise, mEventRegistry: {…}, mMessages: null, id: "id-1580302908064-25", oData: Array(3), …},...
oDropModelData = (3) [undefined, undefined, undefined], oDropModel = constructor {pSequentialImportCompleted: Promise, mEventRegistry: {…}, mMessages: null, id: "id-1580302908064-25", oData: Array(3), …}

Answer (score 1):

Can you see data in the original table? 
Setting of the model is incorrect: the JSONModel constructor needs an object rather than an array as listed in your `initData` function. It seems like a binding problem to me...

I just tried to modify your code as follows and everithing works fine:

```
    onDrop: function (oInfo) {
        var oDragged = oInfo.getParameter("draggedControl"),
            oDropped = oInfo.getParameter("droppedControl"),
            sInsertPosition = oInfo.getParameter("dropPosition"),

            oDraggedParent = oDragged.getParent(),
            oDroppedParent = oDropped.getParent(),

            oDragModel = oDraggedParent.getModel(),
            oDropModel = oDroppedParent.getModel(),
            oDragModelData = oDragModel.getData(),
            oDropModelData = oDropModel.getData(),

            iDragPosition = oDraggedParent.indexOfItem(oDragged),
            iDropPosition = oDroppedParent.indexOfItem(oDropped);

        // remove the item
        var oItem = oDragModelData.datalist[iDragPosition];
        oDragModelData.datalist.splice(iDragPosition, 1);

        if (oDragModel === oDropModel && iDragPosition < iDropPosition) {
            iDropPosition--;
        }

        // insert the control in target aggregation
        if (sInsertPosition === "Before") {
            oDropModelData.datalist.splice(iDropPosition, 0, oItem);
        } else {
            oDropModelData.datalist.splice(iDropPosition + 1, 0, oItem);
        }

        if (oDragModel !== oDropModel) {
            oDragModel.setData(oDragModelData);
            oDropModel.setData(oDropModelData);
        } else {
            oDropModel.setData(oDropModelData);
        }
    },

    initData: function (datalist) {
        //just an example
        var oData = {
            datalist: [{
                Connectormodule: "one",
                settingA: "one",
                settingB: "one"
            }, {
                Connectormodule: "two",
                settingA: "two",
                settingB: "two"
            }, {
                Connectormodule: "three",
                settingA: "three",
                settingB: "three"
            }]
        };

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
        this.byId("ConnectorModuleTable").setModel(oModel);
    },
```

Comment: i am getting datalist as :- 0: {connectormodule: "Guide ", settingA: "1", settingB: "2 ", custom: ""}
1: {connectormodule: "Module ", settingA: "1", settingB: "2 Left", custom: ""} and i am getting error for    var oItem = oDragModelData.datalist[iDragPosition];
 as Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: What version of Ui5 are you using? Is your model named or unnamed?

Comment: i am referring SAP UI5  documentation (https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/controls)

Comment: I think is better to refer to the documentation of the stable release (you can find it here https://ui5.sap.com/) but my question is different... if you press ctrl+shift+alt+P on your running UI5 app what is the SAPUI5 version listed?

Comment: i am using SAPUI5 version:-1.73.2

Comment: Anyway I just only modified the two methods reported above and everything works fine with the latest version (1.73.1). I noticed one thing: make sure that your columns aggregation and your cells aggregation in the ColumnListItem has the same cardinality!

Comment: ...actually for me it works also with different cardinality....

Comment: my cells aggregation is:-var oItem = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: [
          new sap.m.Text({ text: Connectormodule }),
          new sap.m.Text({ text: settingA }),
          new sap.m.Text({ text: settingB }),
          new sap.m.Text({ text: customValue }),
          new sap.m.Button({
            text: "Delete",
            press: [this.deleteRow, this]
          })
        ]
      }); and columns aggregation as mentioned above in xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206910/discussion-between-cmdd-and-sophie).